# formlayout Putting content in caption cell in vaadin

Tags: vaadin7

In form layout the content is starting from 3rd column. Like form layout content cell.

My problem is, i am using form layout for showing the header. I am puuting one label with caption on form layout.

As this label dont have value, the content is starting from 3rd column as content.

Content cumming as

column1(caption cell)           column2(error cell)            column3(content cell)

how i can show the content from column1(caption cell)?

regards
Arvind

Answer (score 0):

The normal way I think only works in Vaadin 7.5.0+ (and maybe only with Valo theme). You add a Label to the from and give it one of the built in h*x* styles.

```
Label section = new Label("My Heading");
section.addStyleName("h2");
section.addStyleName("colored"); //this will just make it colored
form.addComponent(section);
```

There is also another way which is a little more hacky.
Add a Label into the FormLayout. Set the caption of the Label to the text you want, but leave the contents empty. Then, set a style on the label, like "form-heading". So:

```
Label l = new Label();
l.setCaption("Heading 1");
l.setStyleName("form-heading");

formLayout.add(l);
```

Then, in your theme, define the style so it looks like what you want. For example:

```
.v-caption-form-heading {
  color: blue;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it works.